# Do all template parameter packs have "empty" as their default value?

Tags: c++, templates, standards

Look at the following code, which apparently both GCC and Clang are happy to accept: [[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d00a095a028b96e)]:

```
template <class ... P1, class T1, class ... P2, class T2, class ... P3>
constexpr int f(T1, T2) {
    return sizeof...(P1) + sizeof...(P2) + sizeof...(P3);
}
int main() {
    static_assert(f(12, 3.4) == 0);
}
```

Why does this compile? Is there a rule in the standard that says that when a template parameter pack can't be deduced, it's assumed to be empty?

Comment: Yes there is, do you want a quote?

Comment: @PasserBy yes please, I've been trying to find it but failing

Comment: Huh, apparently it only applies to _trailing_ packs. [temp.arg.explicit](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.arg.explicit#3.sentence-2). Big mistake. And [msvc doesn't compile](https://rextester.com/GVV94209).

Comment: Well the posted code is ill formed no diagnostic required because you demand the packs are empty.  Fix it, or if you prefer I could post a snarky answer.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Snark avoided :)

Answer (score 1):

[temp.param] 17.1/15 intends to make your code ill-formed, based off the example:

> ```
>  // U can be neither deduced from the parameter-type-list nor specified
>  template<class... T, class... U> void f() { } // error
> ```

But the text is slightly unclear:

> If a template-parameter of a class template, variable template, or alias template has a default template-
>   argument, each subsequent template-parameter shall either have a default template-argument supplied or be a
>   template parameter pack. If a template-parameter of a primary class template, primary variable template, or
>   alias template is a template parameter pack, it shall be the last template-parameter. A template parameter
>   pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template parameter unless that template
>   parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list (11.3.5) of the function template or has a default
>   argument (17.9.2). A template parameter of a deduction guide template (17.10) that does not have a default
>   argument shall be deducible from the parameter-type-list of the deduction guide template.

The problem is a *template parameter pack* is not a *template parameter*; while `T..., U...` is banned for template classes, the wording blocking it from a template function appears slightly wrong.

You could also argue that the impossibility of passing types to those packs runs afowl of:

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>   [...]
>   every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack,

but that is a serious stretch.